# Find out the path to the original file of a hard link

Tags: linux, sh

Now, I get the feeling that some people will think that there was no original file of a hard link, but I would strongly disagree because of the following experiment I did.

Let's create a file with the content `pwd` and make a hard link to a subfolder:

```
echo "pwd" > original
mkdir subfolder
cp -l original subfolder/hardlink
```

Now let's see what the files output if I run it with shell:

```
sh original
sh subfolder/hardlink
```

The output is the same, even though the file `hardlink` is in a subfolder!

Sorry, for the long intro, but I wanted to make sure that nobody says that my following question is irrelevent.

So my question now is: If the content of the original file was not conveniently `pwd`, how do I find out the path to the original file from a hard link file?

I know that linux programs seem to know the path somehow, but not the filename, because some programs returned error messages that `<path to original file>/hardlinkname` was not found. But how do they do that?

Thanks in advance for an answer!

Edit: Btw, I fixed the error messages mentioned above by naming the hard links the same as the original file.

Comment: I simply do not understand what you are trying to show with that intro, sorry. What is `sh` meant to do here? Usually it refers to a basic shell, but that would mean that the file in question has to be executable which is completely unclear. If that "output" refers to an error message or similar, then sure, the path is different, since you specify a different input. That is to be expected. But what is it meant to show? Sorry, but it is true: _there is no concept of an "original file" in a hard link_.

Comment: I followed your explanation for your test and came out with the same output. As expected. You have to consider that the output of the `pwd` command you execute in your example refers to the current working directory _of the shell process_, not that of some file. Since you start the shell process from the same directory, they have the same working directory in both cases. That has _nothing_ to do with hardlinks. It simply is how shells and the `pwd` command work

Comment: With `sh` I meant the Linux/Unix Bourne Shell. The `sh` is necessary, because I didn't make my files executable. It is not necessary for the files to be executable if you open them with `sh`. And, no, you missed my point. The output is not different, and that is what confuses me.

Comment: I already answered to that above. I said: "If that "output" refers to an error message or similar, then sure, the path is different". If it is not an error message but the output of the `pwd` command then yes, the output is identical. As to be expected.

Comment: @arkascha: How do you explain the error messages of linux programs? How do they know the path to the original file if I started the program with the hard link files? Thanks for the explanation about `pwd`. It cleared up some things.

Comment: They don't. I do not see a connection of this late question to the issue above. What do you mean here?

Comment: I have never experienced such a thing. In general you should try to avoid hardlinks. Could you give us more details about "linux programs" and their error messages? What programs? How to reproduce..?

Comment: @nox: I installed wine, and because it was not working that well I installed [wine-staging](http://pipelight.net/cms/page-wine.html) which seems to be a modified version of wine which works better. Now, the path to wine-staging is `/opt/wine-staging/bin/wine`. I have to type it every time I want to use the modified wine version. So, I created a hard link to that program in my home directory. I initially called it something different than `wine`, because I thought it might cause problems with the non-modified wine, but that returned the err msg above. Once I changed the name to `wine` it worked

Comment: Of course, I had to use `./wine` instead of just `wine` to use wine-staging instead of wine.

Comment: Off-topic: I advise you to create a symbolic link instead of a hl. For example if you update your wine, your hard link will not update. Symbolic links refer to files by name (in contrast to hard links which refer by inode). This is most commonly what you want.  
Maybe you should create a new `alias`. This were my favorite solution by the way.  
On-topic: In this special case, I do not know, how (or better why) wine does this. I guess it knows its directory `/opt/..` and just runs in there (pwd=/opt/...). You could test it by renaming the "original" file. Then your hl should not work either (?)

Comment: I did exactly that. Thanks for the tip. After the update of wine the hard link would still be the old version of win.

Answer (score 3):

> But how do they do that?

By looking for the same inode value. Here's one way you can list files with the same inode:

```
find /home -xdev -samefile original
```

replace /home with any other starting directory for `find` to start searching.

> how do I find out the path to the original file from a hard link file?

For hard links there are no multiple files, just one file (inode) with multiple (file) names.

ADDENDUM:

> is there no other way to find the hard links of an inode than searching through folders?

`ln`, `ls`, `find`, and `stat` are the common ways of discovering and querying the filesystem for inodes. Then depending on what next you want to accomplish, many file, directory, archiving, and searching commands recognize inode values. Some may require a special `-inum` or `--follow` or equivalent option to specify inodes.

The find example I gave above is just one such usage. Another is to combine with xargs to operate on all the found files. Here's one way to delete them all:

```
find /home -xdev -samefile original | xargs rm
```

Look under --help for other standard os commands. Most Linux distributions also come with help files that explain inodes and which tools work with inodes.

Comment: Do you maybe know the following: The linux OS seems to keep count of hard links, since `ls -l` returns the number of hard links of a specific file. Does that mean linux knows the paths to the hard links, and if yes, is there no other way to find the hard links of an inode than searching through folders?

Comment: OK, I know a little bit more now after my question [How does the ls command find the hard link count?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35353712/how-does-the-ls-command-find-the-hard-link-count). Linux probably does *not* know the paths to the hard links of an inode, because it does not need to.

Answer (score 0):

`pwd` is the `present working directory`, so of course, the output should be the same, since you didnt `cd`'t into your subfolder.

Sorry to say, but there is no "original" file if you create other hardlinks. If you want to get other hardlinks of a file, look at [How to find all hard links to a given file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/201920/how-to-find-all-hard-links-to-a-given-file) for example.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @Emacs User. Your example of pwd is irrelevant and confused you.

There is no concept of original file for hard-links. The file names just act as a reference count to the content on the disk pointed by the i-node (see `'ls -li original subfolder/hardlink'`). So even if you delete the original file hardlink still points to the same content.

Comment: Yeah, I misunderstood how `pwd` works. In Java for example it would be the directory the file containing `pwd` is stored in, but in Bourne Shell it is the directory the file is opened from. Very confusing... :-/

Comment: A child process cannot change the pwd of the parent process, which is what you are expecting in Java.

Comment: @EmacsUser: Now that I think about it, it is the same in Java, too. You can't use or import classes of other folders, unless they are in a package structure relative to the directory you started the program from. So, the `pwd` in Java programs is the same as in Bourne Shell. Man, this was really confusing.

Answer (score -1):

It is impossible to find out as all hard links are treated the same way pointing to one inode.

Comment: @EmacsUser: How can one find out the first hard link created? Just for your information, I asked my question to be deleted, but the mods ignored my request... :(

Comment: Sort on the last command in my response by date and pick the first one. Or read the --help files for any of the commands to automatically show only the first one.