# How does the ls command find the hard link count?

Tags: c, linux

How does the command `ls -l` count the number of hard links of an inode?
Does it use the Linux API or is it code that requires deeper knowledge of the Linux kernel source code?

I am not, yet, able to understand the source code of `ls`, because I just started learning C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a real simple program illustrating the user of `stat()` to find hard-link counts:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int main ( int argc, char ** argv ) {
    int     i;
    struct stat st;     /* stat puts info here */

    for (i = 1; i < argc; ++i) {
        if (stat(argv[i], &st) == -1) perror(argv[i]);
        else printf("%s has %d hard links\n", argv[i], st.st_nlink);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

*(Pass it one or more file-names on the command line)*

Comment: Thank you very much!  Now I understand the answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/35353739/3668527 more clearly! So, a `struct stat` variable is a container where information about files can be stored with the `stat` function, and after that you can just read the field `st_nlink` field of the `struct stat` variable that was previously filled with information.

Comment: Exactly.  And there is other useful info in the stat struct too!

Answer (score 3):

It calls [`stat`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat) to get information about the file (in a `struct stat`). Then it looks at the `st_nlink` field of the `struct stat`.

Comment: I am sorry if this a dumb question, but is `stat` linux api or from c library?

Comment: It's OS-specific. It's in POSIX, so you'll find it on all Unix-like OSes.

Comment: And there are two `stat`s? One is a `struct` and one is a function?

Comment: Yes, there are two things called `stat`.

Comment: Ah, OK. Thanks! That answered my question!