# What does &struct_name and sometype ** variable_name do exactly?

Tags: c

I come from a Java background and I started reading K&R, but the progress is extremely slow, because I know most of it, but still have to read everything again. So, I was thinking that I could maybe ask here some things about the C programming language to learn things a **lot** faster.

What I want to know is

1. What happens when I pass a struct variable with a `&`-prefix as an argument to a function? The code sample that I am trying to understand is:

   ```
   struct somestruct st; 
   somefunction(&st);
   ```

   1.1. What kind of signature does `somefunction` need to have and what exactly is passed?

   1.2. A pointer to the struct variable would be `*st` instead, right?
2. What does it mean when a function has as a parameter `sometype ** variable_name`? The code that I want to understand is:

   ```
   int main(int argc, char **argv)
   ```

The whole code that I want to understand is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35355069/3668527

Please no explanations of the code. I know what it does. I just need to know what those strange new C operators `&` and `**` mean.

Edit: Oh, and please tell me how these operators are called!

Comment: `&` is take address of (some variable) and `*` is pointer of (some variable) , `**` is pointer of pointer of (something). Any C book should tell you those.

Comment: Too broad man. K&R certainly has all you need.

Comment: Note that `*` in a declaration (variable or function) has a subtly different meaning from the unary `*` operator in an expression.  `char *x = *argv++;` illustrates — where `argv` is the argument to `main()`.  The `*` before `x` indicates that it is a pointer type; the `*` before `argv` is a dereferencing operator.  Of course, the binary `*` is just multiplication.

Comment: Be aware that the original K&R syntax is obsolete. Make sure the editition was updated sometime this millennium, preferably even this decade.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt K&R 2nd edition is almost as obsolete as the 1st. I don't believe any updates have been made during the past 25 years or so. It is simply an outdated book filled with poor style and dangerous practice, it should be avoided entirely.

Comment: That is valuable info, @Lundin. So, in summary, starting with C by learning from K&R is a bad idea.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Yes, the book is only good for nostalgia.

Answer (score 2):

`&` get pointer to that variable.

The function signature should be: `void somefunction(struct somestruct *st)`, i.e. it will accept pointer to that structure.

`strct *` means pointer to strct, `strct **` means pointer to pointer to strct etc.

Comment: Ah, OK. `&` creates a pointer out of a normal variable. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> What happens when I pass a struct variable with a &-prefix as an argument to a 
>   function? The code sample that I am trying to understand is:
>   The & operator returns the adress of an object.
>
> What kind of signature does somefunction need to have and what exactly is passed?

```
void somefunction(struct somestruct  *pointer);
```

You can put in "const" in a few places to tell the compiler that you don't want to allow the method to do any changes.

> 1.2 A pointer to the struct variable would be *st instead, right?

Depends in which context "*st" is used, if you just want to create a pointer do it that way:

```
somestruct  *pointer = NULL; // or init it somehow
```

> Edit: Oh, and please tell me how these operators are called! Thanks!

They are called adress operators.

> What does it mean when a function has as a parameter sometype ** variable_name

That means that the parameter is a pointer pointing to another pointer.

Comment: Thank you for the signature of `somefunction` and the name of those operators! Now I can look them up!